# Prove that ${\prod_\limits{n = k_0}^{\infty} (1 - a_n)} \;$ converges to positive value

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, infinite-product

Request help proving the following:

**Given:** 
(1) For all $n > 0 , \;a_n > 0 $ 
(2) ${\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}a_n} \;$ is convergent. 
(3) There exists $k_0 \in \mathbb{Z^+} \; $ such that for all 
$ k \geq k_0 , \; a_k < 1.$

**To prove:** $\displaystyle{\prod_{n = k_0}^{\infty} (1 - a_n)} \;$ converges
to a $\lambda$ that is strictly greater than $0$.

**Motive:** On [pages 10-11 of this pdf,](http://bit.ly/pdf-khinchin) the assertion helps prove that if 
${\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}a_n} \;$ is convergent, then the infinite
continued fraction given by $[a_0; a_1, a_2, \cdots]$ does not converge to a
value.

**Partial Work:** My query has actually already been answered by 
[this question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2288203/sum-n-1-infty-a-n-converges-iff-prod-n-1-infty-1-a-n-conve)  Reviewing the answers in the previous question, I agree 
that $\ln(1-a_n) \sim -a_n \ (n \rightarrow +\infty).$  I also agree that it is 
**sufficient** to show that $\sum_\limits{k\geq k_0} \ln(1 - a_k)$ is convergent.

**Stumbling Block:** I googled on "real analysis equivalence test convergence"
and could not find any online reference.  I am actually requesting an 
$\epsilon,\delta$ argument that 
${\sum_\limits{k\geq k_0}a_k} \;$ convergent implies 
${\sum_\limits{k\geq k_0}\ln(1 - a_k)} \;$ convergent.

**Alternative Request:** An online reference to the equivalence test or an 
$\epsilon,\delta$ argument that : 
given two series $\{a_k\}$ and $\{b_k\}$ where 
$\lim_\limits{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = c \neq 0,$ **then** $\sum a_k$ convergent iff $\sum b_k$ convergent?

Comment: Your alternative request is false in general, and to be true the statement should require that at least one of the two sequences $(a_n)_n$, $(b_n)_n$ stays positive for $n$ big enough (or stays negative; but basically does not change sign).

Comment: Your alternative request is answered by the [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test), with some caveats like Clement's comment above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Taylor series we know that$$\ln(1-a_n)=a_n+\dfrac{a_n^2}{2}+\dfrac{a_n^3}{3}+...$$also we know that $a_n\to0$ therefore $$\exists b\in\Bbb N\qquad,\qquad \forall n>b\to 0<a_n<\dfrac{1}{2}$$which leads to $$0<a_n^2<\dfrac{a_n}{2}\\0<a_n^3<\dfrac{a_n^2}{2}<\dfrac{a_n}{4}\\0<a_n^4<\dfrac{a_n^3}{2}<\dfrac{a_n}{8}\\.\\.\\.$$which leads to$$\ln(1-a_n)=a_n+\dfrac{a_n^2}{2}+\dfrac{a_n^3}{3}+...<a_n+\dfrac{a_n}{2\times 2}+\dfrac{a_n}{2^2\times 3}+\dfrac{a_n}{2^3\times 4}+\dfrac{a_n}{2^4\times 5}+...<2a_n$$for $n>b$. Therefore $$\sum_{n=b+1}^{\infty}\ln(1-a_n)<\sum_{n=b+1}^{\infty}2a_n$$which concludes that $\sum_{n=b+1}^{\infty}\ln(1-a_n)$ is convergent and so is $\sum_{n=k_0}^{\infty}\ln(1-a_n)$

Comment: Good job! ${}$ +1

Comment: @Mostafa Ayaz very nice, thanks

Comment: @Clement C. very interesting, thanks

Comment: @Fimpellizieri that was just what I wanted, thanks.

Comment: ??? You started with an inequality that says that a negative number is less than a positive number, and ended with an infinite series of negative numbers being less than an infinite series of positive numbers.

Comment: @zhw i think that mostafa ayaz intended that - ln(1-a_n) = ...

Answer (score 2):

Because $\ln '(1)=1,$ we have $\ln(1+u)/u\to 1$ as $u\to 0.$ Thus there exists $\delta >0$ such that

$$\tag 1 \frac{\ln (1+u)}{u}< 2\,\, \text { for }|u|<\delta.$$

Now $\sum a_n <\infty$ implies $a_n\to 0.$ Hence there exists $N_0$ such that $n\ge N_0$ implies $0<a_n<\delta.$ For such $n$ we then have by $(1)$ that

$$\ln(1-a_n) > -2a_n\,\implies\,
\sum_{n=N_0}^{\infty} \ln (1-a_n) \ge \sum_{n=N_0}^{\infty} -2a_n.$$

The series on the right converges. Hence the so does the series on the left, being a sum of negative terms. This implies the desired result.

Comment: creative and slick.  if i hadn't already "accepted" 1st answer, i would have accepted yours.